# Ansible Undefined variable in vars_files item but the variable was defined using set_fact

Tags: linux, ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to select a local file based on what motherboard version exists on the machine on which Ansible will deploy those files.

So my approach was to use dictionary in format {"*<board_name>*" : "*<local_file>.yml*"}. And use this dictionary to populate a new variable (`pcu_config` here) that will finally store the name of the file to be used by ansible. I've gotten so far as shown in my implementation, and I'm get undefined variable error at line

```yaml
vars_files:
    - "{{ playbook_dir }}/pcu_config/{{ pcu_config }}"
```

But as can be seen in the ***debug*** msg in the image of the output just before this play, `pcu_config` is indeed defined(and is the correct filename too).

```
- name: Find the pcu_config
  hosts: vehicle
  gather_facts : no
  vars:
    pcu_config_dict:
      VirtualBox: virtual.yml
      n1: n1.yml
      n2: n2.yml
      n3: n3.yml
      n4a: n4a.yml
      n4b: n4b.yml
      
  tasks:
        - name: Find the motherboard name
          shell: cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/board_name
          register: board_name

        - name: Find the motherboard version
          shell: cat /sys/devices/virtual/dmi/id/chassis_version
          register: board_version

        - debug:
            msg: "board_name : {{ board_name.stdout }}, board_version: {{ board_version.stdout }}, {{pcu_config_dict}} "

        - name: Assign the PCU_config file for other than n4's
          set_fact:
            pcu_config: '{{pcu_config_dict[ board_name.stdout | default("this cpu does not exist in the dict")] | default("") }}'
          when: board_name.stdout != "n4"

        - name: Assign the PCU_config file for n4
          set_fact:
            pcu_config: '{{pcu_config_dict[board_version.stdout | default("this cpu_version does not exist in the dict")] | default("") }}'
          when: board_name.stdout == "n4"


- name : Check pcu_config is available elsewhere in playbook
  hosts: vehicle
  tasks: 
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ pcu_config }}, {{ playbook_dir }}"

- name: Deploy software to vehicle
  hosts: vehicle
  vars_files:
    - "{{ playbook_dir }}/pcu_config/{{ pcu_config }}"
    - "{{ playbook_dir }}/os_config/deb-files-cache.yml"
    - "{{ playbook_dir }}/os_config/python_dep.yml"

  roles:
      - role: logger_network
        tags: base
```

Here is the output when I run this playbook on my virtual machine.
[image: Output of ansible playbook]

Suggestions welcome to solve the X or Y problem.(ref @Zeitounator's comment)

Comment: From our [ask page]: _**DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)_

Comment: Also, from the error it seems, the variable which is undefined is in the file `"{{ playbook_dir }}/pcu_config/{{ pcu_config }}"`, since you are providing none of those files, that would be complicated to answer you.

Comment: `since ansible doesn't allow using vars inside tasks` <= can you please be a bit more specific ? Literally all the ansible work I've done since I started years ago would not run if this was not possible. Moreover, why issuing cat on a target file when the information you need is available in `ansible_board_name`, `ansible_board_version`, and alike once facts are gathered ?

Comment: If by `ansible doesn't allow using vars inside tasks` you mean it does not allow `vars_files` it is true. But you can use `include_vars` during the play. And honnestly, you should review your question and add more details and context (more specificatlly the example content of your var files) because I have a very strong feeling this can be fixed in a much simpler way. See [x/y problem](https://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε I find the image of the output to be more readable. And I'll take my chances with the readers using screen readers, or those using SO on mobiles or don't have access to image sites. Moreover the input code is in the correct format in case someone wants to copy or edit it. So lets not turn recommendations into rules and use fair reasoning for different cases.

Comment: @Zeitounator You're right, this piece of code can be highly optimized. I'm very new in software engineering, hence this mess. But I searched a lot and couldn't find how to use the facts `ansible_board_name`, could you guide me further.

Comment: @Zeitounator I didn't add the content of var files because the error is in templating the variable refering to those files. Btw I solved this by adding `cacheable : yes` to `set_facts`, but if you have any pointers in making this more efficient, I'll be happy to hear them.

Comment: @Zeitounator nvm `ansible_board_name` has been changed to `ansible_product_name`. So, I'm using that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best approach but to access the variables set by `set_facts` elsewhere in the playbook, using `cacheable: yes` works.

```
        - name: Assign the PCU_config file for other than n4's
          set_fact:
            pcu_config: '{{pcu_config_dict[ board_name.stdout | default("this cpu does not exist in the dict")] | default("") }}'
            cacheable: yes
          when: board_name.stdout != "n4"

        - name: Assign the PCU_config file for n4
          set_fact:
            pcu_config: '{{pcu_config_dict[board_version.stdout | default("this cpu_version does not exist in the dict")] | default("") }}'
            cacheable: yes
          when: board_name.stdout == "n4"
```